# Reversing a String (Theoretical)

Tags: c, string, reverse

The question I have is not actually about code, I know how to reverse a string.

This is a very common interview question, so I would like to clarify what I think the correct solution is.

So the premise starts, you have a counter at the end of the string, and then one at the beginning. And you swap the two characters they point to.

There are two ways to do this...

Three variables, an (A,B,Temp) that you can use a common method to switch A and B.

Two variables, using XOR three times between A^B, B^A, A^B.

Both achieve the same result, but I have read that while the first method actually uses more variables it actually doesnt use more memory because the smarter C compilers these days recognizes that Temp is a temp variable and uses the CPU to store it and then garbage it rather than putting it on the memory stack. Because of this, would the first solution be "better" since its more understandable and in essence uses just the same amount of memory as the 2nd solution?

Thanks!

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)

Comment: Don't use XOR swap. It only works on integral types and even then, there's no advantage.

Comment: Can you add some psuedocode, perhaps?

Comment: The temp swap version [won't always need an extra register](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Data_Transfer#Data_swap). Trust the compiler.

Comment: I think you know the answer.  You need to stop trying to be clever.  Compilers usually do a better job than you can.

Comment: In a simple example program, `gcc -O3` compiles both versions basically to the same code on my machine, both versions _omitting_ XOR instructions (the only XOR instructions used are used to initialize values to 0). The only reason to use XOR swap I can think of (with modern compilers) is in a macro function where you can use the same macro for arbitrary integer types.

Comment: Maybe change your title to something like “Should I use XOR swap” or ”How to swap values (theoretical)”, as this question is rather unrelated to reverting a string.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the clearest way to swap two `int` objects is as follows:

```
int a, b; /* these are the variables we want to swap */
...
const int old_a = a;
a = b;
b = old_a;
```

The name `old_a` (unlike the generic `temp`) describes the value it holds. The `const` makes it clear (both to a reader and to the compiler) that the value will not change after initialization.

You might prefer to enclose the above in a block (under C90 rules you have to):

```
{
    const int old_a = a;
    a = b;
    b = old_a;
}
```

This restricts the scope of the temporary, but the braces add visual clutter.

Any decent compiler should be able to generate good code for this -- at least as good as you'd get using the xor hack.

The xor hack, on the other hand:

```
a = a ^ b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;
```

*might* suffer from problems on exotic systems where the type of `a` and `b` has trap representations; you're not likely to run into such an issue, but writing more straightforward code gives you one less thing to worry about. It can't be used for non-integer types (there's no `^` for pointers, floating-point values, or structures). If the things being swapped aren't simple variable names, it's possible for `a` and `b` to refer to the same object:

```
int *p0, *p1;
*p0 = *p0 ^ *p1;
/* etc */
```

in which case both values will be clobbered.

The xor hack is very clever. That's not a good thing. Anything that's "very clever" should be viewed with grave suspicion.

You tagged the question "C", but you used the word "theoretical" in the title, so I'll mention that in languages that support it, you can do something like:

```
(a, b) = (b, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

All other things being equal, the more readable code is better. And in this case, that would be the code that uses a Temp variable. Furthermore, it is applicable in situations where the elements being reversed are not simple integer objects.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is the one that works.
A good solution is one you can read.

Good and correct is nearly always best.  Especially for an interview.